# How do I make my previous messages disappear in Visual Studio 2013 console applications? (C++)

Tags: c++

So if I write a piece of code like this:

```
string name, feeling;
cout << What is your name?" << endl;
cin >> name;
cout << "Hello, " << name << "!"<<endl;
cout << "So how are you feeling today?" << endl;
cin >> feeling;
```

I get the output:

```
What is your name?
James (input from user)
Hello, James!
So how are you feeling today?`
```

But I want it to remove the first message and the input, so the user will get just this on the console window:

```
Hello, James!
So how are you feeling today?
```

Comment: What platform do you use?

Comment: Then refer to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As long as you stay on the same line, it's usually pretty easy to use a combination of `\b` (back-space) and/or `\r` (carriage return without new-line) and some spaces to go back to the beginning of a line and write over what's displayed there.

If you need to do (much) more than that, you can use the Windows console functions such as [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025.aspx) and [`FillConsoleOutputCharacter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682663.aspx) to write data where you want it, overwrite existing data, etc.

If you care about portability to Linux and such, or already know how to program with curses, you might prefer to use [`PDCurses`](http://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm) instead. This is basically a re-implementation of the `ncurses` programming interface on top of the Windows console functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on windows environment, try this

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout  << "This is the first line";
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "This is the line on clear console" << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```